# Error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Program

Tags: actionscript-3, import, flash-cs4, compile-time-constant

I'm trying to link my .as file to my Flash program. Below is the code from my .as file:

```
package com.project {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;

public class Program extends Sprite{
    public var value:Number;

    private var max:Number;
    private var min:Number;

    function draggable()
    {
        min = bar_mc.y;
        max = bar_mc.height - Erhu_H3_btn.height;
        Erhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
    }

    function dragHandle(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Erhu_H3_btn.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0,min,0,max));
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }

    function stopDragging(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Erhu_H3_btn.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    }
}
}
```

Below is the code in my Flash file:

```
import com.script.Script;
stop();
var Program:Program = new Program();
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I keep getting error 1046! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed importing statement

```
import com.project.Program
```

Comment: What type of file is 'Program'? Because I currently only have the flash file and the .as file...

Comment: I think you should read some docs on what type is because I have the feeling that you do not understand these basics. In your particular case Program is Type. Here is how you defined it in your own code public class Program extends Sprite

Comment: I realise that - sorry! I'm quite new to programming, and I haven't been as assiduous in my reading as I perhaps should be! However, when I add the code you asked me to below 'import com.script.Script' in my flash file, all I get is two (identical) errors telling me the definition for program is not found (1172), as well as the original error 1046. Sorry to bother you again!

Comment: Oh, and I should probably mention that I don't actually have a folder called 'project'. Is that impacting on my result in any way? Sorry again!

Comment: Then you should read some basics of Actionscript programming. The line package com.project at the top of your first code tells that this file should be inside com/project directory.